# Bundle ID not allowed to change in itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, cfbundleidentifier, bundle-identifier

I have not uploaded the binary but itune does not allowing me to change the bunlde id from manage-apps. If any body have clue on it plz let me know or I need to recreate ?

Thanks,

Comment: Once you create it with 1.0 then you can not change it.you have to generate another version for same app.

Answer (score 2):

Once u create the Bundle ID,You cannot change in itunes Connect.Only option you can delete and re do Again

Or you can Specify the same Bundle ID in Your Xcode Project

Comment: In case if i delete then i need to give another app name ? and one thing still i have not uploaded binary

Comment: It is Ok.But Now you can not delete it.

Comment: If u delete the Information ,You still can create App name as Before after deletion

Comment: @20120 : you Mention in your answer, we can delete App from iTunes Connect.Can you please tell me how to delete created App from iTunes connect?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html you can refer this

Comment: @20120 you mean that i need to delete the app information and resubmit it using new bundle id

Comment: @Smita can you give me any alternate solution for this

Comment: ya...this time you need to Specify your required Bundle ID

Comment: @20120 the link which you gave for delete app thats nice but in my case i am not getting delete app option

Comment: There is no any alternative solution. You need to delete this App from iTunes Connect and have recreate it with required version number.Now you can use previous bundle ID.But the version number must be same in plist's Bundle version.

Comment: Reject this Binary is nothing but Deleting the App

Comment: but from where i have to delete there is no delete option :(

Comment: thank you for your valuable support